# What is the best way to visualize a DataTable while debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ide, datatable

I have some very big `DataTable`s, which I need to see their content while debugging.
Is there a better way to do that other than opening the `Column`s' and `row`s' lists Properties in the Watch panel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the DataTable visualizer; hold your mouse over the variable and click on the magnifying glass this will open the DataTable visualizer.

Btw, there are more VS2010 visualizers for other actions.
I really like the WPF Tree visualizer: hold your mouse on a WPF control and click the magnifying glass ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. How do you get there? (-:

Comment: Helping people 5 years in the future. This is super awesome! Thanks Microsoft

Answer (score 3):

Open the [DataSet visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d480bk47.aspx).  Either hover over the variable in the source code or look at one of the variables in a debugger window (Locals, Auto, etc.)  Then click the magnifying glass.

MSDN article on [How to Use a Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdakzs26.aspx).